# Decrypt String with variable in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to decrypt a string that contains the variables of my structure.
I want my variables in my string to be replaced by the correct value after decryption.

My result is that I get the string with the variables and not replaced by their value.

How to do that ?

Here is my code.

```
type (
Test struct {
    Login   string `form:"login"`
    Email string `form:"email"`
    Age  string `form:"age"`
})
```

Inside my function

```
tst:= Test{}
textToEncrypt := 
"login:tst.Login;email:tst.Email;timestampunix:1563804616"
textEncrypted := service.EncryptText(textToEncrypt, keysToEncrypt)
```

After he encrypt, I have an encrypt string, until here it's OK.

When I call my Decrypt Function, he return the string like above , but I want the value of the variable inside the string, the value of the variable struct?

It's possible?

Comment: If you are asking whether there's a function in the standard library that parses your particular format then no, there is not.

Comment: Whether your string is decryptable depends on the format that EncryptText uses. We don't know what that format is. Where did you get that function? You need to ask the author of that function.

Answer (score 0):

As stated there are not any functions in the standard library to parse your format. It seems that you use semicolons and colons as a delimiter for this format. With that in mind we can create custom code to parse through it.

```
splitString = strings.Split(str, ";")

example.Login = GetLastIndex(splitString[0])
example.Email = GetLastIndex(splitString[1])
example.Age = GetLastIndex(splitString[2])

func GetLastIndex(str string) string {
    return str[strings.LastIndex(str, ":")+1:]
}
```

Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/UTrazkQ5EI-